# iOS change height of a uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to change dynamically the height of a uitableview inside my view.

I tried with this code inside the viewDidLoad:

```
self.theTable.rowHeight = 90;
self.theTable.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,900);
```

The first line works and the height is changed, but the second doesn't work!

How can I do this?

Comment: Take a look at ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318030/how-do-i-resize-the-uitableviews-height-dynamically

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try resetting the bounds like this:

```
CGRect bounds = [tableView bounds];
[tableView setBounds:CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x, 
                            bounds.origin.y, 
                            bounds.size.width, 
                            bounds.size.height + 20)];
```

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me.

```
self.myTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,40,320,480);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that you can change the height of a non-autolayout UITableView by simply adjusting it's frame in viewDidAppear or viewDidLoad.

However, if you want to change the tableView's height after this point (for example, when someone taps a button) then that is not possible for tableViews created in Storyboard. You CAN change the height after the table is loaded for tableViews created programmatically.