# Change size of UIViewTable to accommodate for AdWhirl Ad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to change the size of my UITableView. I have an ad on the bottom of my view, and when I scroll, the ad scrolls along with it. I was wondering how I can change the size of the UITableView so the ad will always remain on the bottom of the view regardless of whether the UITableView is being scrolled or not. I have tried changing the size of the frame of the TableView, but this doesn't work.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 tableView.frame = CGRectMake()...
}
```

I also tried changing it in the scrollViewDidScroll: selector, but no luck. Is there anyway I can change the height so it doesn't conflict with my ad on the bottom? Thanks!

Comment: Do you use IB to make the UITableView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With UITableViewControllers `self.view == self.tableView`. This is a problem in your case because the desired effect you want requires sibling views (two views added to a common superview) but there is no "superview" for self.tableView.

You have to create a new UIViewController subclass that has a UITableView and your ad view as two subviews. You will need to handle things like setting the data source and delegate for the table view, as well as deselecting table view cells when the controller appears. This is a little more work and requires some care, but is definitely doable.

I've thrown together a quick example below that will get you started:

```
// Header
@interface CustomTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)tableViewStyle;

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, retain) UITableView* tableView;
@end

// Source
@interface CustomTableViewController()
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) UITableViewStyle tableViewStyle;
@end

@implementation CustomTableViewController

@synthesize tableView;
@synthesize tableViewStyle = _tableViewStyle;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)tableViewStyle {
  if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil])) {
    _tableViewStyle = tableViewStyle;
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)loadView {
  [super loadView];

  self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithStyle:self.tableViewStyle];
  self.tableView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth
                                     | UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleHeight);
  self.tableView.delegate = self;
  self.tableView.dataSource = self;
  [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];

  // Create your ad view.
  ...

  adView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleWidth
                             | UIViewAutoresizingMaskFlexibleTopMargin);
  [self.view addSubview:adView];

  [adView sizeToFit];
  self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height - adView.frame.size.height);
  adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - adView.frame.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width, adView.frame.size.height);

  [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
  self.tableView = nil;

  [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  NSIndexPath* selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
  if (nil != selectedIndexPath) {
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath animated:animated];
  }
}

@end
```

Comment: I tried this and end up with my view being black and nothing showing up on screen.

Comment: It's very likely that you will need to implement a custom table view controller.

Comment: I am pretty new to Objective-C and have to push an app for a client by tomorrow. Is there no easy quick way to do this?

Comment: Added an example of creating a custom UITableView controller.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to solve this problem is just use .XIB file for your UITableView and then you change the height very easily using Interface Builder.

If you dont have IB file then please go through this post: [How do I resize the UITableView's height dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318030/how-do-i-resize-the-uitableviews-height-dynamically)

Comment: I already tried editing it dynamically and it didn't work.I also adjusted it using the Interface Builder but no luck..